# Caller ID not displaying after android 6 update

Tags: updates, android-versions

My infinix x510 has stopped displaying caller ID for incoming calls. It only displays the phone numbers  without the names. And the contacts are in my phone book.  I'm thinking it's a result of recent update to Android 6 M. Please How could I resolve this issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoX/comments/3y2ziu/recent_calls_not_showing_caller_id_after/cyh9mg9) on Reddit, I fixed this problem by removing my Google account and adding the Google account again.